# Transfer from Tegel Berlin to city center

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, berlin, txl

I will soon have a 7-hours transit at Tegel Berlin and of course I want to visit the city centre of Berlin. I just want to take the bus and go to the center where I can enjoy my hours, see the beautiful Berlin and eat something. I don't want the place to be far away from the airport.

- Unfortunately, I did not find clear information on the net, which bus
  number should I take and which station should I get off the bus?
- What can I see in this place?
- How to buy the ticket!

Hope to get an answer before my travel time.

Comment: Are you a Schengen area resident or have a visa? Are you laying over for an international (out of Schengen area) flight? The time needed for security will limit your time available to tour. Frankly, 7 hours, which sounds like a lot, in a large European city where (I can only assume) you don't speak (or read) the language, will go _very_ quickly. Not knowing your way around might get you unable to return in time.

Comment: I am an eu citizen, so I will not face these kinds of problems or delays..

Comment: @CGCampbell Tegel is a very odd airport with per-gate security and no generic transit area whatsoever. It makes absolutely no difference where you are going, everybody has to go through the whole shebang every time and sterile transit is only possible if arranged in advance. In many ways (including the location and architecture of this airport), Berlin isn't really like a typical large European city.

Comment: That system allows for very short waiting times. Usually I arrive 15-20 minutes before departure and that's more than enough (not recommended if you don't know what you are doing!). I'll be sad when TXL is gone.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/getting-from-berlin-tegel-airport-to-downtown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any answer to your question will of course be slightly opinion based, but if you are more into shopping and getting some food and not necessarily into seeing historical sights (both is probably not manageable in 7 hours anyway), you don't have too many options.

I would have taken the 109 bus from Tegel to Adenauerplatz, located on the famous [Kurfürstendamm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurf%C3%BCrstendamm) avenue. The bus departs every 10 minutes and the ride takes 20 minutes. From Adenauerplatz, you can stroll 2km along the avenue towards Zoologischer Garten, passing many shops, cafés or places to eat.

When you reach the area around Zoologischer Garten, which can be considered the city centre of the former West Berlin, there are a few historical sights if you are interested e.g. the [Kaiser Wilhelm Memorial Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_Wilhelm_Memorial_Church), or if you have time, you can also continue a few hundred meters along Tauentzienstraße and visit [Kaufhaus des Westens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhaus_des_Westens) on Wittenbergplatz, one of the largest department stores in Europe or even visit the Zoo itself.

From Zoologischer Garten, you can take the X9 bus back to Tegel, which also takes 20 minutes and departs every 10 minutes.

One way tickets for public transport within the city of Berlin cost 2.70€ and allows you to transfer between different lines and interrupt your journey withing two hours after stamping the ticket. A daily pass is available for 6.90€ (is paid off if you plan to make three or more trips). Tickets can be bought from the bus driver, cash only and don't expect the bus driver to change larger bills. At the airport, you also find ticket vending machines at the bus stop, from which you can buy multiple tickets at once, which must be stamped later when you use them.

Comment: thanks, that is a great answer.. so you mean when I get off the bus at Adenauerplatz, I can there get shopping and have a good walk and eat. I dont have to take the Underground or tram ?

Comment: Yes, you can get from Tegel to Adenauerplatz with the bus without any transfers, walk to Zoologischer Garten and take the bus back to Tegel also without any transfer.

Comment: One quick question regarding the tickets. if I buy one multiple ticket from the vending machine at the airport in order to use one for my way to center and the other for the back way to the airport. in this case, is the back ticket "time limited"?. i.e. should I for instance use it only after two hours, or I can use it after several hours.

Comment: @yaya: I thought I made that clear with my answer: "which must be stamped later when you use them"? If you buy tickets from the bus driver or in a tram, the tickets are already validated and for immediate use. If you buy tickets from vending machines at bus or subway stops, you have to stamp the tickets yourself when using them (potentially later).

Answer (score 7):

Berlin Tegel Airport (TXL) is quite a bit outside the city and there is no direct train connections there - you'll have to take the bus and change to either S- or U-Bahn (S=faster trains, longer distances between stops; U=underground, fairly tightly mashed net).

The local transport company is BVG and [here](http://fahrinfo.bvg.de/Fahrinfo/bin/stboard.bin/en?ld=0.1&&newrequest=yes&whichTask=) you find their listing of routes etc by depature station and route planning. At the airport there are four bus routes:

[image: TXL OPNV map]

- **Bus X9/109/128** take you to *U Kurt-Schumacher-Platz (Berlin)* where you can change to the **U6** underground and from that the whole network is accessible
- **Bus TXL** takes you to *S Beusselstr. (Berlin)* or *S+U Brandenburger Tor (Berlin)* - the former allowing quick change to the S-Bahn, the latter bringing directly to Brandenburg Gate, one of Berlin's sights.

[Here is a pdf](http://www.bvg.de/de/index.php?section=downloads&cmd=58&download=399) (or: [alternative, central parts only](http://www.bvg.de/de/index.php?section=downloads&cmd=58&download=400)) of the train network (both S- and U-Bahn) - and at the top left of the central octagon you'll find the bus connections to TXL mentioned, including their connecting train stations.

For [tickets](https://shop.bvg.de/index.php/tickets) there is an integrated system covering Bus, U- and S-Bahn and prices organized by zones - TXL airport is in zone B, while the center is covered by zone A, so you'll need to get the tickets for zones A&B. Tickets can be bought at machines at the airport or from the bus driver.

As to what to see - Berlin is a big city with a huge variety of sights. For a short transit visit, I guess Brandenburg Gate and the Reichstag, and current govt buildings are a must - train stations: *S Brandenburger Tor* and *U Bundestag* will serve you well. For everything else do consult any page listing sights in Berlin and then the BVG website or Google maps for train route instructions.

Comment: (+1) Actually, public transportation connections are not very good but Tegel is so central that a court ordered it closed. It's 7-8 km from the Brandburger Tor (compared to 20km between Schiphol and Amsterdam and 30+ between Heathrow or Charles-de-Gaulle and their respective city centre).

Comment: Even if there is no rail or subway station at the airport, the bus connections are actually quite good and relatively fast. The X9 bus departs every 10 minutes and takes 20 minutes to Zoologischer Garten and with the TXL bus departing every 6 minutes, you will be at Brandenburger Tor in less than 30 minutes. Going from Tegel by bus, you are much faster in the city centre of Berlin than by rail or subway from most other international airports.

Answer (score 4):

Where exactly do you want to go in Berlin ? 
Here's the [BVG](http://www.bvg.de/en/), the transportation company for the Berlin area, there's a route planner on their home page

There's an airport shuttle called TXL which operates every few minutes according to their website. 
You can buy tickets at the airport, any other S-Bahn or U-Bahn station and even on the bus or tram [(reference)](http://www.bvg.de/en/Tickets/Other-ways-to-buy/At-sales-outlets)

Comment: I would not ask the question if I know the places in Berlin.. read the question plz ( place to enjoy my hours and see the beautiful berlin, not far away from the airport)

Comment: @yaya well Berlin is a big city, the airport is outside and you said center, there's many ways to end up in the city.

Comment: well, where is the closest place to the airport where one can make quick shopping and find various restaurants?

Comment: The closest place to the airport where one can make quick shopping and find various restaurants? The airport. Duty Free shopping and fast food. See? My answer fits your question, but is probably not what you want, which is why these kinds of questions are frowned upon.